# Firefox with selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, selenium, mink

I have followed the tutorial on: 
github[dot]com/aik099/en-mink[dot]behat[dot]org/blob/master/index[dot]rst

to run `Mink/selenium` on a php script.

I am running selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0 with Firefox 28 (went down from version 37), but keep on getting an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError' with message 'Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: Error: no display specified Error: no display specified  in...
```

When searching the error online, I have only found that I should downgrade Firefox below 35 for the current selenium version. What am I then still doing wrong?

Then I went and installed Google Chrome, with the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError' with message 'The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.opera.driver system property;`

for more information, see github[dot]com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver. The latest version can be downloaded from github[dot]com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases' in...

Extra info:
Running this script on a VPS with centos 6 installed.

PHP script of code:

```
    <?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver(
    'firefox', 'thewebsitebase'
);
//have replace firefox with google-chrome

// init session:
$session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);

// start session:
$session->start();

// open some page in browser:
$session->visit('thewebsite');

// get the current page URL:
echo $session->getCurrentUrl();

// get the response status code:
echo $session->getStatusCode();

// get page content:
echo $session->getPage()->getContent();

// evaluate JS expression:
echo $session->evaluateScript(
    "return 'something from browser';"
);

?>
```

Comment: the first error is because you are probably trying to run Selenium on a machine that doesn't have a display. Are you using just a command line linux?  if so, then you should research headless browsing.  the second error is because the property `webdriver.chrome.driver` must be set.  one way you can do this, is by doing `export webdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver` but based on the first error, i think you'll run into the same issue

Comment: Thanks for the info :) I have now moved over to zombie driver, as it seems to be the only option for headless browsing with js support. From your comment I needed to add export ... thing. In my case now: export NODE_PATH="/usr/lib/node_modules/zombie". But is this supposed to be added in some file, or a command?

Comment: @sircapsalot have tried the export NODE_PATH="/usr/lib/node_modules as a command for zombie.js, then nothing happens thereafter. Running the php script keeps getting an error:
'Server process has been terminated: (8) [ module.js:340 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'zombie' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) at Module.require (module.js:364:17) at require (module.js:380:17) etc. do you maybe know where my problem lies?